# Python Pandas replacing nan's in one column conditional on observations in another column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data frame in python pandas:

```
current_data = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['3'+'*NY', '3', '2', '2'+'*NY', '1', '7'], 'Y': [np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 8, np.nan]})
```

What I want to get is:

```
needed_data = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['3'+'*NY', '3', '2', '2'+'*NY', '1', '7'], 'Y': [4, 4, 5, 5, 8, np.nan]})
```

So, I want to replace nan's in Y column that correspond to observations in X with "*NY" part, to numbers in Y that correspond to observations in X that have the same numeric part but without "*NY"

Comment: Your code does not run and it is a little unclear, can you post desired output

Comment: The code must be working now. I did not get how to post the python output here, so I posted as a code

Comment: Because your code didn't work I couldn't visualise the desired output, now I can. However your explanation is a confusing, for Y values that are `NaN` you want to lookup the corresponding `Y` value where the `X` values matches the numeric component of `3xNY` correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit more annoying to code, basically we can apply a custom function that performs the lookup for you:

```
In [106]:
# define our function
def func(x):
    # test to see if the asterisk is present
    if x.find('*') > 0:
        # perform a lookup on a slice of the passed in string
        return(current_data.loc[current_data.X==x[0:x.find('*')],'Y'].values.max())
# using loc assign to column 'Y' where it is null the returned calculation of the apply
current_data.loc[current_data.Y.isnull(),'Y'] = current_data[current_data.Y.isnull()]['X'].apply(func)
current_data
Out[106]:
      X   Y
0  3*NY   4
1     3   4
2     2   5
3  2*NY   5
4     1   8
5     7 NaN
```

Comment: Indeed it works :) thank you I think I'll have to spend an hour or so to get how it works, but in any case thanks